# What JSF components allow for 'insert' in the partial ajax update?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I'd like to code a JSF component that retrieves only the latest data from the server-side and appends them to the page on the client. In jsf.js I see different ways of handling partial updates: update, delete, insert (depending on the XML that comes back from the component after partial update). Are there any built-in components that use ? How can I write my own?

Comment: the latest data are pushed to the application OR is it a user action that fetches the latest data?

Comment: Is your problem in partial updating OR in dealing with the received data?

Comment: @Rami Both, new data can be fetched following user action or by ajax polling. What I want to avoid is accumulating data in the backing bean and having to request everything for each ajax triggered re-render. I only want to retrieve increments and append rather than reset the component contents.

Comment: I grepped through Mojarra (JSF impl) sources - the component that deals with partial upgrade is called PartialViewContext(Impl) and control PartialViewWriter to encode updates in XML. PartialViewWriter has a couple of different ways to sent updates: startUpdate or startInsertAfter/startInsertBefore. But none of the startInsert* methods are used in the Mojarra codebase.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just in case somebody finds it useful...

I don't think Mojarra supports any other kind of update besides replacing the component rendered content, you probably need some more advanced controls from PrimeFaces or alike. What I did in the end was "hijacking" the ajax response and re-structuring the XML nodes to force jsf.js to perform an "insert" on my control:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function (data) { 
        if (data.status === "complete") { 
          var doc = data.responseXML;
          if (doc.firstChild.nodeName === "partial-response" 
                  && doc.firstChild.firstChild.nodeName === "changes") {
            //we are dealing with proper response
            var changes = doc.firstChild.firstChild;
            var update = changes.firstChild;
            if (update.nodeName === "update") {
              changes.removeChild(update);
              var insert = doc.createElement("insert");
              insert.setAttribute("id", update.getAttribute("id"));
              changes.appendChild(insert);
              var after = doc.createElement("after");
              after.setAttribute("id", update.getAttribute("id"));
              insert.appendChild(after);
              after.appendChild(update.firstChild);
            } 
          } 
        } 
      });
```